# Transitividade dos verbos das frases?

Tags: verbos, transitividade-verbal

Na frase logo abaixo:

> O Brasil **exportou** muito café.
>
> O pai perguntou à mulher quem quebrou a janela.

Qual é a transitividade dos verbos das frases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para descobrir a transitividade de um verbo é necessário fazer algumas perguntas a ele:

1. Quem exporta, exporta algo.
2. Quem gosta, gosta de algo/alguém.
3. Quem pergunta, pergunta algo a alguém.

No primeiro caso, podemos verificar que o verbo **exportar** é *transitivo direto*, isso porque ele pede um complemento, mas não pede uma preposição na pergunta. Podemos chamar esse complemento de *objeto direto*.

No segundo caso também podemos confirmar que o verbo é *transitivo*, contudo — nesse contexto — ele é *transitivo indireto* devido a utilização da preposição *[de]* na pergunta que fizemos, ou seja, temos um *objeto indireto* como complemento do verbo.

No terceiro e último caso, temos um verbo *transitivo direto e indireto* (ou apenas um verbo *bitransitivo*). Nesses casos o verbo irá pedir dois complementos: Um objeto direto e um objeto indireto (não necessariamente nessa ordem).

**Frase 1:**

```
 O Brasil    exportou   muito café.
└────┬───┘ └────┬────┘ └────┬─────┘
     │          │           └─ Predicado (Muito = Ad. Adverbial de Intensidade / Café = Objeto direto)
     │          └───────────── V.T.D (Quem exporta, exporta algo)
     └──────────────────────── Suj. Sim. (O = Ad. Adnominal / Brasil = núcleo)
```

---

**Frase 2:**

**Oração 1:**

```
 O pai  perguntou   à mulher 
└──┬──┘└────┬────┘ └───┬────┘
   │        │          └─ Objeto Indireto (à = Prep. A + Artigo A / Mulher = Núcleo do Objeto)
   │        └──────────── V.T.D.I (Quem pergunta, pergunta ALGO A ALGUÉM
   └───────────────────── Suj. Sim.
```

**Oração 2:**

```
quem quebrou   a janela.
    └───┬───┘ └────┬────┘
        │          └────── V.T.D (Quem quebra, quebra algo)
        └───────────────── Objeto Direto pois complementa o verbo
```

Como bem lembrado pelo "Artefacto", aqui temos uma *oração subordinada substantiva objetiva direta*.

Oração = Pois tem verbo
Subordinada = Pois depende da oração principal
Substantiva = Pois podemos substituir pelo pronome "Isso"
Objetiva Direta = Pois complementa o verbo da oração principal

---

Perguntar ao verbo ajuda, contudo nem sempre você terá a resposta correta (recorra ao dicionário também). Alguns verbos possuem significados diferentes a depender da transitividade, por exemplo:

> **Gostei** a comida e não **gostei** dela.

Na frase acima temos dois verbos iguais com transitividades diferentes. Se fosse necessário reescrevê-la, poderíamos fazer da seguinte forma:

> **Provei** a comida e não **gostei** dela.

Outros verbos possuem um objeto com preposição, mas nem por isso ele é um *V.T.I.*, por exemplo:

> **Comi** *o pão* (**V.T.D.** + *Objeto Direto*)

> **Comi** *do pão* (**V.T.D.** + *Objeto Direito Preposicionado*)

Comment: Estou "enferrujado", mas acho que deu para entender um pouco. :D

Comment: Faltou dizer que a 2a oracao da 2a frase é o objeto direto de perguntar.

Comment: sim.Deu sim pra entender .Obrigado

Comment: Valdeir, muito impressionantes esses teus esquemas; tens de me ensinar a fazer isso :). Creio que foi a primeira vez que vi *gostar* com o sentido 'provar'. Eu diria "degustar"; bem, na verdade diria simplesmente "provar". No [Aulete](http://www.aulete.com.br/gostar) não vem. Vem é um outro uso transitivo direto que eu também não conhecia (aceção 11), 'aproveitar, desfrutar', "espero que gostes as situações mais prazerosas"; mas diz que é pouco usado.

Comment: @Jacinto No [Priberam](https://dicionario.priberam.org/gostar) aparece no sentido de provar. Realmente é pouco usual, assim como o verbo *assistir* no sentido de habitar/morar.

Comment: Sobre os esquemas, uso o [**Box Dawing**](http://jrgraphix.net/r/Unicode/2500-257F) (em especial os caracteres: 2500, 2502, 2514, 2518, 251C, 2524, 252C e 253C) e, por fim, seleciono o texto e pressiono `Ctrl` **+** `K`