# Qual a diferença entre objeto indireto e complemento nominal nestas orações?

Tags: sintaxe

Eu encontrei estas duas orações em um site sobre gramática.

*Frituras fazem mal ao fígado.
Ofereceram esmola ao mendigo.*

Nessas duas orações, *ao fígado* é considerado complemento nominal de *mal*, e *ao mendigo* é considerado o objeto indireto de *ofereceram*.

Todos os testes que eu faço para diferenciar os dois casos têm resultados iguais.

*Fazer algo a alguém.
Oferecer algo a alguém.*

Por que *ao fígado* não é considerado o objeto indireto do verbo *fazer*; e *ao mendigo*, complemento nominal de *esmola*? Existe algum teste que evidencie a diferença entre os dois?

Comment: O verbo fazer ,apresentado no contexto supra, é transitivo direto: *Quem faz, faz algo*. Ele é utilizado como bitransitivo em poucas situações como em *ser utilizado de determinada maneira: na escola, a professora fez de diretora*. É comum fazermos perguntas ao verbo e adicionar uma pitada de curiosidade e isso nos leva ao erro como em: *quem faz, faz algo **para alguém***, *quem morre, morre **de alguma coisa*** etc. Recomendo a leitura de [Transitividade dos verbos das frases?](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/a/5517/2759)

Comment: "Ao mendigo" é claramente complemento indireto; mas é possível que haja ambiguidade no "mal ao fígado". A posição da gramática que viste é que "mal ao fígado" é complemento direto de "faz", e que "ao fígado" é complemento nominal de "mal", isto é, completa o significado de "mal". Mas este artigo no [Ciberdúvidas](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/fazer-bem-analise-sintatica/33148) apresenta o exemplo completamente análogo, "O tomate faz bem à saúde", e considera "à saúde" complemento indireto, sendo o complemento direto apenas "bem".

Answer (score 2):

Não vejo por que razão não se possa considerar *ao fígado* objeto indireto de *fazer* ("fazer algo a alguém/alguma coisa"). Podemos ter:

> (1) Frituras fazem-lhe mal.
> (2) A que é que as frituras fazem mal?

Os quais são testes típicos para identificar o objeto indireto. (1) funciona talvez melhor se *lhe* se referir a um ser animado, mas isso não altera a análise. E o facto de (1) admitir redobro indica também que *lhe* ocupa realmente uma posição argumental:

> (3) Frituras só *lhe* fazem mal *a ele*.

Quando muito, podemos defender que *fazer mal* funciona como um predicado complexo com o significado de *prejudicar* e que *ao fígado* é um complemento deste conjunto. É uma das possibilidades apontadas [neste artigo do Civerdúvidas](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/analise-sintatica-da-frase-fazer-mal-em-provocar-me/35694) ou [nesta dissertação](http://livros01.livrosgratis.com.br/cp034347.pdf).

Comment: Mas pode também ser classificado como complemento nominal de *mal*? O Cunha e Cintra classificam como complemento nominal *a ambas* em *a vida dele era necessária a ambas*, e isto também passa os testes: *era-lhes necessária*, *a quem é que é necessária?* Ou faz diferença *necessária* ser adjetivo?

Comment: Faz diferença o verbo _ser_ ser um verbo copulativo; _fazer_ mantém a grelha argumental de 3 lugares apesar de algum grau de gramaticalização. Na gramática da Maria Mateus é explicitamente defendido que não existe uma predicação secundária nesta construção (segunda metade da pág 313 [aqui](http://artefacto-test.s3.amazonaws.com/verbos_leves.pdf)).

Answer (score 1):

Acho que nesse caso, devemos apenas prestar atenção na ideia transmitida pela oração. Vejamos.
Fritura faz mal. Pronto, não fica dúvidas nem  temos sensação de faltar algo. Uma fez, que a palavra mal, por si só já completou o sentido do verbo. Toda a adição que vier, não será mais para o verbo, porque o mesmo já está com completo.   Frituras fazem mal.  Note  que mesmo que tiremos "ao fígado", desta oração, não sentiríamos falta dele

Agora, se lhe digo, "Ofereceram esmola", logo fica a pergunta, quem?  e para quem? Logo, a palavra esmola é insuficiente para completar a mensagem transmitida pelo verbo. Nesse caso, mesmo com a palavra esmola, o verbo necessita de algo mais para ter sentido completo,  pois se lhe digo,  "ofereceram esmolas". Ficará um vácuo em sua mente. Porque a frase está completamente vaga. Sem sentido, portanto o verbo requer algo mais para completar o sentido da mensagem enquanto que se lhe digo, frituras fazem mal, está oração está completa. Não precisa de mais nada.
Para finalizar. A diferença clara é, o complemento nominal, pode ser retirado da frase, sem prejuízos à compreensão
Enquanto o objeto direto e indireto é essencial em uma frase completa

Answer (score 0):

Olá! Como mencionaram, "fazer" é transitivo direto. Podemos substituir "mal" por "malefício" e veremos o complemento nominal com mais clareza. O verbo "oferecer", nesse caso, é um verbo transitivo direto e indireto, e o próprio contexto evidencia essa transitividade.

Dê uma olhada nestas páginas:
[https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/analise-sintatica-da-frase-fazer-mal-em-provocar-me/35694#:~:text=(i)%20Mal%20desempenha%20a%20fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o,%C2%ABEle%20f%C3%A1%2Dlo.%C2%BB](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/analise-sintatica-da-frase-fazer-mal-em-provocar-me/35694#:%7E:text=(i)%20Mal%20desempenha%20a%20fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o,%C2%ABEle%20f%C3%A1%2Dlo.%C2%BB) e
https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/fazer-bem-analise-sintatica/33148.