# Por que é certo dizer: fui ao banheiro?

Tags: gramática

Por que dizemos "fui ao banheiro", se não fomos por ele, mas por nós mesmos?

Comment: *Quem vai, vai a (preposição) algum lugar*, logo o correto é *fui ao (preposição + artigo) banheiro*. Se trocarmos a preposição **a** por **em**, daria ideia de [meio de transporte (pag 63)](https://www.novaconcursos.com.br/blog/pdf/Retifica%C3%A7%C3%A3o-UFBA-Auxiliar-Administra%C3%A7%C3%A3o-Mat%C3%A9ria%201-L%C3%ADngua%20Portuguesa.pdf): *Fui no avião*. Exemplos: *Fui **ao** carro* = Fui até o carro / *Fui **no** carro* = Fui de carro. Para saber mais, recomendo a pergunta [Transitividade dos verbos das frases?](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/a/5517/2759)

Comment: Por que razão pensas tu que *vou ao banheiro* deveria significar ’vou pelo/de banheiro’? A preposição ***a*** só tem esse significado nas expressões *ir a cavalo* e *ir a pé*; de resto para indicar o meio de transporte usamos *de*: *vou de burro/bicicleta/barco/avião*; ou *em*,  como já disse o @ValdeirPsr, neste caso mais para indicar um veículo/animal em particular: *vou no carro do João/num airbus A380*. A preposição ***a*** em *vou ao banheiro* indica o destino da deslocação; em Portugal toda a gente a usa assim; creio que no Brasil tende a ser substituída, >>

Comment: As pessoas aqui no Brasil falam muito "fui no banheiro", o que confunde um pouco. Às vezes me pego falando assim sem querer. A dúvida foi que não vamos para o banheiro, porque ele não precisa de nós, mas nós dele. E dizem muito que "a" é "para".

Comment: >> especialmente na linguagem informal, por *em* (*vou no banheiro*) ou por *para/pra*. Não posso dizer grande coisa acerca da distinção entre *ir no banheiro* vs *ir para o banheiro*, porque em Portugal não dizemos *ir em* para indicar destino; usamos *ir a* e *ir para*, mas há uma diferença entre as duas, que creio que também há na linguagem formal no Brasil (vê [esta pergunta sobre este ponto](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/791/qual-a-diferen%c3%a7a-de-ir-a-e-ir-para)).

Comment: Renanlinux, simplificadamente é a transitividade verbal, assim como disse @ValdeirPsr.

Comment: Em Portugal não é usual  a palavra banheiro. É mais comum Casa de banho.

Answer (score 0):

Quando você vai PARA algum lugar, essa palavra pode ser alterada pela preposição A ou AO.
Essas são as formas corretas:

- Fui para o banheiro; e
- Fui ao banheiro.

Mas sua pergunta é contrária, certo?
Da forma que escreveu, pareceu-me que quis dizer "Fui pelo banheiro".
Agora mesmo ao ler, sei que já entendeu al. Quando você vai "por algum lugar", você não fica ali...apenas passa pelo local. Seria algo como "fui ao meu quarto passanso - fisicamente - pelo banheiro" mas vou mudar a frase tentando uma forma mais fácil de entender: "fui AO estádio PELA avenida principal".
Novamente, IR A ALGUM LUGAR é diferente de IR POR ALGUM LUGAR. Quando você vai A ALGUM LUCAR, o destino já está certo. E quando VAI POR ALGUM LUGAR, apenas diz uma forma de chegar ao destino.